# How do I extract the best features when using BayesSearchCV?

Tags: python, feature-selection, scikit-optimize, bayessearchcv

When using BayesSearchCV from Skopt for Feature Selection, how can I extract the feature names of the optimal set of features? I only know how to get the number of features together with other hyperparameters but am unable to find how to get the names of these optimal features.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can access this by calling

```
opt.best_params_
```

https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html#skopt.BayesSearchCV